# Reset a random number generator with same seed (C#)

Tags: c#, random, random-seed

Here's my situation:

I'm making a game in C# which randomizes the positions of all the objects on the screen everytime you begin a new level. To do this I've just declared a

```
random r = new Random();
```

I then decided that even though I want to randomize whenever a new level is begun, I want each level to be the same every time.. In other words, the positions of the things on level 1 will always be the same, every time you start the game, and so on for all the other levels.

To do this, I added a seed to the generator:

```
random r = new Random(mySeed);
```

This works perfectly - when I exit the game and start it up again, the random positions in level 1 will be the same every time.

However, here's the problem:
I understand that when you give the Random object a seed, it uses that seed to generate its list of numbers, which is obviously why all my r.Next()s are the same no matter how many times I re-open the program. BUT, it seems I have to COMPLETELY restart the entire program in order to reset it and get back to the first item in the list again...

In other words, If the player dies during level 1, you go back to the main menu.. But then when it calls r.Next(), it's of course not going to give me the correct level 1 positions.

I tried to solve this by simply re-constructing the object when you die, for example:

```
//other death code in here
r = new Random(mySeed);
//back to main menu
```

But that doesn't seem to make a difference - it'll still continue on with the sequence from where it was before..

So does anyone have a clue how I can point back to the beginning of the random list WITHOUT having to restart the whole program?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're replacing the `Random` instance used in your main program (and not just your method's local variable)?

Comment: If you want each level to be generated the same every time, it's not truly random, right? Why not precalculate all the level objects and store them?

Comment: Reconstructing it works, here's [an example](http://ideone.com/hxcxnx). So there's something wrong elsewhere with your code.

Comment: @Douglas - Yes, I only have one Random instance which is public and static in one class, which gets used by all the other methods.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but any thought on keeping r.Next() in a static list<int>?  then, on death, the player uses that list until the end and then starts using r.Next() again?

Comment: @DaveZych I could do that, but I built the entire game originally around the idea that every level would be different, so now that I'm generating each level the same every time, I figured it'd be a lot easier to just use a seed instead of store the data for every single level

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Hmm that's peculiar, you're right. I'm using different minimum and maximum boundaries with r.Next() give things x and y positions that are within the boundaries of the screen, so maybe the min and max is affecting it in some way?

Comment: @JasonWilczak So are you suggesting I just place all the random numbers I'm going to need in a list at the start, then just pull all of them out of the list as needed? I could do that but I think it might be quite a long-winded work around

Comment: Yeah, I mean, just a thought.  You could do a Dictionary<int,List<int>> where the key is the level and the value is the numbers that have been generated.  Then, once you reach the end of that levels list, you pull r.Next() and keep going (updating the List<int> also).  I would suggest using objects and abstracting out the way the number is retrieved, but just something to think about.

Comment: @JasonWilczak That's a really interesting idea, I'll bare that in mind next time! Just managed to solve the problem now anyway, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it would appear Pierre-LucPineault was correct.

I did manage to fix it simply by re-constructing my Random object - I was just doing it in the wrong place before.

Before, I was doing
    r = new Random(mySeed)
upon death, and for some reason this didn't work.. But I instead moved that bit of code to be called when you click on New Game on the main menu, and now it works!?

I even added a breakpoint before and the code was definitely getting executed.. So then I did the whole, step through every single line, type debugging...
Turned out there was a point in between then and the next time I start the game again when I was doing an r.Next() so that messed the whole sequence up!

So yeah, re-constructing the object works perfectly fine, I'll just be more careful next time where exactly I do that ;)